# SQL Find Records that came for for first time with Value 5 with in last week

Tags: t-sql

I have a table similar to this

```
  personId     Value    createdTime
    1991126   19.00     2018-08-05     
    1991126   16.00     2018-06-15 
    1991126   18.00     2018-08-06 
    1991206   32.00     2018-08-02
    1991431    6.00     2018-08-06
    1991431    7.00     2018-08-07
```

I am trying to find personId's that came since last week for **first time** with value 5
Here I should show 1991206,1991431 because 1991126, has already 16.00 on 2018-06-15 
So the personID should not have history with of >5. So we have to compare previous records.

I tried

```
Select distinct personId,Value,createdTime
where value>=5 and createdtime>= Dateadd(Day,-7,Getdate())
```

Comment: I also tried with Rank but didn't work well

Comment: did you try min(createdTime) ?

Answer (score 0):

First find all personId's that came since last week (`having min(createdTime) >= Cast(Dateadd(Day,-7,Getdate()) as date)`) and then check if they have a value higher than 5 (`max(myvalue) > 5`):

```
SELECT personID
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY personID
HAVING min(createdTime) >= Cast(Dateadd(Day,-7,Getdate()) AS date) AND max(Value) > 5
```

Comment: This is working fine when a PersonID has Created date older than week but when a person has 2 values with in same week it's giving me two result set Can I get only the first record

Comment: For instance Delete record 1991126   16.00     2018-06-15 it has two records but I only want to show 2018-08-05 because that's the first

Comment: What are you after? You said `personId`, so this query returns only personsID with no duplicates.

Comment: Yes this is giving me distinct person ID's but when I also add Value and created (only for created dates in same week) I am getting two records. Can I only get the "first"

Comment: I don't see your exact query so hard to tell. For sure you can wrap it into another select: `SELECT * FROM (<YOUR QUERY>) as x WHERE x.createdtime <ADD YOUR CONDITION>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to first restrict the records to `Value > 5`, then apply a ranking, and in the end find the records with ranking 1 that are from since last week. Restricting the values and applying the ranking can be done in just one query, but criteria for the ranking must be applied in an outer query. Also, the criteria for the date must not be applied before ranking, because that would rank only the records from last week. I prefer to use *common table expressions* for nesting queries:

```
WITH
  Greater5 (personID, Value, createdTime, rnk) AS (
    SELECT personID, Value, createdTime,
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY personID ORDER BY createdTime)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Value > 5
  )
SELECT personID, Value, createdTime
FROM Greater5
WHERE rnk = 1
  AND createdTime >= Dateadd(Day,-7,Getdate())
```